# Как узнать какие запросы посылает расширение Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-extension, расширения

Вообщем как узнать все запросы которые посылает расширение Chrome? Или только с помощью отладчика в хроме(вкладка "Network")?

Comment: Самый просто вариант действительно через вкладку Networks. Только учтите, что расширение может состоять из нескольких различных модулей: background, popup, content-scrtipt. Сетевые запросы надо проверять для каждого по-отдельности.

Comment: Можно использовать сниффер (wireshark например)